# HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using "Microsoft Interop Word dll for resume parsing. My functionality is working fine at my local machine. I have two server one is Windows 2008 and Windows 2012 server. I have deployed my code on both server. In Windows 2008 is working find and in windows 2012 giving exception like -

> "HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out."

When I debug my code at Windows 2012 server. Request going for infinite time and after some time its giving such types of error "HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out."

It is not executing this code of line and going for infinite -

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application Application = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

Comment: i can suggest to use open xml dll from microsoft

Comment: Note that an error code ending with `0005` usually means `access denied`.

Comment: Do you have word installed on the other machine, too? Also, this might not work, when you run it in a service.

Comment: Yes, I have installed. Its working fine in my windows 2008 server and getting error on windows 2012 server. I have same configuration and software except windows.

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt :Yes, I have installed. Its working fine in my windows 2008 server and getting error on windows 2012 server. I have same configuration and software except windows

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: where I can give access for same.

Comment: @viveksachan: Does your application run as a service?

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt: Not getting?